# Как изменить имя файла при сохранении в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ссылка, которая автоматически создается javascript'ом

```
<a href="http://cs6-11v4.vk-cdn.net/p16/c1282386c68489.mp3" download="" style="background: #AFA">save</a>
```

При клике по ней предлагается сохранить файл с именем `c1282386c68489.mp3`.

Как сделать так, что бы имя файла было другим? Например `Бетховен - Лунная соната`. Нужно именно на ходу менять имя файла при сохранении (без связи с сервером), при этом разумеется не портя ссылку.

P.S.: И как оформить HTML код, чтобы была кнопка "Выполнить" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 атрибут `download` входит в спецификации HTML5 и явно указывает на то, что ссылка является именно ссылкой на скачивание файла, а не навигационной ссылкой. Можно указать `download` как логический атрибут или со значением, которое является новым именем файла.

Например, при клике по ссылке

```
<a href="asdasdaasd.mp3" download="song">Скачать</a>
```

появится диалог сохранения файла с именем song.mp3 (расширение файла будет добавлено автоматически) вместо asdasdaasd.mp3. Однако стоит заметить, что прием работает, если файл лежит на том же сервере, с которого загружена страница. А именно:

> Firefox в силу своей параноидальной системы безопасности разрешает скачивать файлы только в пределах одного домена. Если файл с атрибутом download окажется на домене отличном от домена сайта - он всё равно **откроется в режиме просмотра**. 
>   Chrome и последняя Opera (движок Chromium/Blink) при скачивании файла с другого домена или сервера разрешат скачать файл с использованием атрибута download, но **не дадут переименовать файл.**
>
> На момент написания этой статьи (07.05.2015 03:33) этот атрибут **всё еще не работает** в браузере от apple - safari, и, кто бы сомневался, Internet Explorer. В Microsoft Edge данный атрибут так же не работает (проверил лично).
>
> [Источник](https://dev3l.ru/17-vebmasteru/54-html5-ispolzovanie-atributa-download)

Собственно это объясняет, почему мне не удалось переименовать песню с сервера ВК.

P.S.: Спасибо @Qwertiy за то что подсказал в какую сторону двигаться.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="нужное имя" ');  
header('Expires: 0'); 
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
header('Pragma: public');
```

Или:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="нужное имя" ');
```

Comment: Это js или php? Как этим воспользоваться? Мне нужно чисто на js, чтобы все был - работаю со страницей.

Comment: @RussCoder, php

Comment: Ну печально, метки такой в моем вопросе нет

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> download=""
> ```

Вот тут в качестве значения надо прописать желаемое имя файла, а не пустую строку.

И напоминаю, что IE атрибут `download` [не ест](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

Comment: Только у меня это не работает, почему-то. В FF и вовсе переходит на страницу с песней, а не выдает окно сохранения файла.  Однако если я применяю этот прием на локалке, то все работает (для своих файлов). Может ли быть так, что ВК, что-то присылает в заголовках, когда пытаешься скачать песню? Можно ли их как-то проигнорировать?

Comment: @RussCoder, бери fiddler и проверяй http-заголовки.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.
Пример от **RussCoder** и от **Qwertiy** не единственный.
Также можно использовать XMLHttpRequest.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', link, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onerror = function(err){
        // Здесь можно выполнять альтернативный вариант
    }
    xhr.onloadstart = function(){}
    xhr.onprogress = function(xhrProgressEvent){
        // Здесь можно обновлять статус загрузки (progressbar)
        // xhrProgressEvent.total -  размер загружаемого файла в байтах
        // xhrProgressEvent.loaded - размер уже загруженного фрагмента в байтах
    }
    xhr.ontimeout = function(){}
    xhr.onloadend = function(){}
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = this.response,
                a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = artist + " - " + title + ".mp3";
            a.style = "display: none;";
            a.onload = function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
            };
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
```

Выше приведенный пример работает если в заголовках ответа сервера присутствует заголовок access-control-allow-origin со значением * (т.е. разрешено всем), либо с именем домена с которого приходит запросом.
Сразу оговорюсь, что музыка ВКонтакте располагается на разных серверах и далеко не все разрешают такой прием.

Answer (score 0):

href="http://cs6-11v4.vk-cdn.net/p16/c1282386c68489.mp3" если по этой ссылке лежит файл просто переименуй его на Бетховен - Лунная соната.mp3 и все

Comment: Нет, файл не на моем сервере. Это ссылка на ВК.